# How to disable dragging down from buttom in this list view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a basic list view in my app And when I drag down from buttom it show the blue widget like in the vid. Is there a way to disable it? Or change it color?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try BouncingScrollPhysics with all lists or grids or scroll view:

```
//ScrollView:
SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
)

//For ListView: 
ListView.builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
}
//GridView
GridView.Builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
)

ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: new ScrollBehavior()..buildViewportChrome(context, null, AxisDirection.down),
          child: SingleChildScrollView()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is Material glow. you can use Cupertino package
else use `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this.

```
class NoSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  NoSplash({this.child});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
        onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
          overscroll.disallowGlow();
          return true;
        },
        child: child);
  }
}
```